# How do I open an Access database (and wait for it to close before proceeding) in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I've tried these, and they did not work (Access opens, but it does not wait:

```
start "C:\program files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" filename.mdb

start /WAIT "C:\program files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" filename.mdb

start /W "C:\program files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" filename.mdb

start filename.mdb

start msaccess.exe filename.mdb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start /WAIT msaccess.exe filename.mdb
```

does the trick.

I don't know why adding the full path makes it fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
PATH="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\; C:\Windows\Command"
START /WAIT MSACCESS.exe "path to mdb file" /X "name of macro"
```